# How to extract the first range in a selection

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the `refedit` control on my `userform`. Is there a way to extract the first range from my selection so I can offset it to retrieve other data from that row as well from "Sheet1" within workbook named `SDPF`. Example: With the `refedit`, I am selecting the `Range("H1044:H1061")`. However, to extract the other pieces of data I just need the first selection, of `H1044`, so I can offset it to retrieve other data, in this case from `Range("B1044")`, `Range("C1044")`, `Range("E1044")`,`Range("F1044")`, and `Range("I1044")`.

Answer (score 0):

You use `Range.Range` method to do that.

```
Debug.Print Range("H1044:H1061").Range("A1").Address '/* will return H1044 */
```

Above will select the first cell in the original Range.
To make it more clear, you can also use `Cells`.

```
Debug.Print Range("H1044:H1061").Cells(1, 1).Address
```

That means retrieving Cell row 1 and column 1 of the `Range("H1044:H1061")`.

Comment: First, thank you for the quick response. Secondly, I don't quite understand the code? Is Range("A1") actually cell "A1" or does equal cell "H1044"?

Comment: It is cell A1 or cell row 1, column 1 of the `Range("H1044:H1061")` which is `H1044`.

Comment: Well, that may pose another problem when I try to offset that new range to retrieve my other needed values. Thank you.

Comment: Why is that? what problem?